# How to stop a method while it's running in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I have a problem and I have to find a solution. I must immediately stop the "Starting" method if the user presses the Cancel button.
I have not fixed the problem yet because I can not block the method while it is running but only at the end or at the beginning of the execution.

ContentView:

```
Button(action: {
 self.Starting()
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .init(uptimeNanoseconds: 0), execute: self.workItem)

}) {
    Text("START")
    }

Button(action: {
 self.workItem.cancel()
 }) {
      Text("CANCEL")
    }
```

Starting method:

```
 func Starting() {
    self.workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.impostazioniChek=true
        }

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if (self.pm.MarksSwitch)
            {
                sleep(UInt32(self.MarksT))
                self.Marks()
            }

            if (self.pm.ReadySwitch)
            {
               sleep(UInt32(self.ReadyT))
                self.Ready()
            }

            self.Start()
            sleep(3)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tm.start()
            }

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: There is no way to stop your function immediately. You can only stop for the next execution and cancel the future call of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cancel because

1) almost all the time work items runs on main (UI) queue, so block it

2) inside work item there is no check for `isCancelled`. DispatchWorkItem.cancel() only marks it cancelled, but does not stops execution you have to do this.

So to make this work it needs to redirect everything not-UI related in your work item into `.background` queue explicitly.

Eg. instead of

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .init(uptimeNanoseconds: 0), execute: self.workItem)
```

use

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { self.workItem }
```

Instead of

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    if (self.pm.MarksSwitch)
```

Just use (because it is already in background)

```
if (self.pm.MarksSwitch)
```

and I'm not sure what is (probably it also should be run on background queue)

```
self.tm.start()
```

And on second add inside block interruption on cancellation by regular check, like below

```
...
}
if self.workItem.isCancelled { // add as many such as needed
    return
}
if (self.pm.ReadySwitch)
...
```